Why was the `future_monitor()` hack needed in David Beazley's demo?
In the PyCon 2015 talk, the following code was presented for a co-routine based Fibonacci server. future_monitor() was added to make the server working (otherwise it would stuck). But why is future_monitor() needed? why is future_done() callback (without writing into socket pair) not enough? Why a socket pair is needed?
from socket import *
from collections import deque
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Pool
from select import select

pool = Pool(4)

def fib(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def fib_server(address):
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(address)
    sock.listen(5)
    while True:
        yield 'recv', sock
        conn, addr = sock.accept() # blocking
        print("connection", addr)
        tasks.append(fib_handler(conn))

def fib_handler(conn):
    while True:
        yield 'recv', conn
        req = conn.recv(100)  # blocking
        if not req:
            break
        n = int(req)
        future = pool.submit(fib, n)
        yield 'future', future 
        result = future.result()  # blocking
        resp = str(result).encode('ascii') + b'\n'
        yield 'send', conn
        conn.send(resp)  # blocking
    print('closed')

tasks = deque()
recv_wait = {}
send_wait = {}
future_wait = {}

future_notify, future_event = socketpair()

def future_done(future):
    tasks.append(future_wait.pop(future))
    future_notify.send(b'x')

def future_monitor():
    while True:
        yield 'recv', future_event
        future_event.recv(100)

tasks.append(future_monitor())

def run():
    while any([tasks, recv_wait, send_wait]):
        while not tasks:
            # no active task to run wait for IO
            can_recv, can_send, _ = select(recv_wait, send_wait, [])
            for s in can_recv:
                tasks.append(recv_wait.pop(s))
            for s in can_send:
                tasks.append(send_wait.pop(s))
        task = tasks.popleft()
        try:
            why, what = next(task)
            if why == 'recv':
                recv_wait[what] = task
            elif why == 'send':
                send_wait[what] = task
            elif why == 'future':
                future_wait[what] = task
                what.add_done_callback(future_done)
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("We don't know what to do with :", why)
        except StopIteration:
            print('task done')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tasks.append(fib_server(('localhost', 25000)))
    run()

[1] Talk's video: https://youtu.be/MCs5OvhV9S4?t=0
Tried removing the socket pair and the server became unresponsive.

In general, futures need to be polled in order to progress. In this instance, this is emulated by the socketpair and future done pushes a message to the notify end socketpair. future_monitor is a task that gets pushed and to continuously poll for the message from the event end and gets handled by the run function.

I think the purpose of future_monitor is to help translate the callback based logic of one part of the code into the socket based logic that the main loop in run uses to wait for activity.
The call to select(recv_wait, send_wait, []) is the main way the program blocks when there's nothing for it to immediately do. The question is, how do you get that main thread to wake up when something happens that's not related to a socket?
In this case, the Fibonacci calculations are being done in a ProcessPoolExecutor, which will make a callback when the calculation is done. But that callback won't wake up the main thread, and the coroutine that's going to use the result of the computation won't check for it until it's iterated on by the main thread.
So that's where the future_done callback and the future_monitor coroutine collaborate. The callback sends a bit of meaningless data (a single 'x' character) over a local socket. The select call that the main thread is blocking on will wake up when that message is sent! The coroutine just receives the 'x' and reschedules itself as waiting on further socket events.
When you removed the future_notify coroutine, nothing will ever get read out of the local socket. Eventually the buffer on the socket will fill up and the writes will block (or maybe raise exceptions). In any case, it won't work any more.

This makes sense, I added timeout to select(), and now the server is able to serve ~1/timeout QPS without  future_monitor() hack. Thanks!

If you're on a platform where socketpair creates AF_UNIX sockets by default (e.g. Linux, macOS) and there's no receiver consuming the sent messages, the stream will eventually block when the OS buffer used to transfer data between the sending and receiving stream sockets fills up: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283323/do-unix-domain-sockets-overflow

Ok, this explains why future_monitor() is needed to unblocking the writer of the socket, but not why we need the socket pair is needed in the first place. In other words, why would not
def future_done(future):
tasks.append(future_wait.pop(future))
work?

The key part of the explanation is at https://youtu.be/MCs5OvhV9S4?t=2063 in the talk: the live demo isn't using the conventional asyncio main loop, so there needs to be a helper task that wakes the main loop up at the appropriate times. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78694993/597742 goes into that aspect in more detail.
